# How to make custom ant task?

Tags: ant

I am learning a new upcoming language known as Visage. This language is almost the same as the Open Source JavaFX 1.3 . My problem is that Visage has its own compiler and to compile a visage file I need to use 'visagec filename.visage' and the run the class file generated I need to use 'visage filename'. I want this task to be automated using the ant script. I also need to include some jar files in the classpath while doing so. Can someone please let me know how to write a custom ant script for the above language. I have already added VISAGE_HOME in my environment variables.

Comment: For using ant's scriptdef (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html) the language must be a supported Apache BSF or JSR 223. The article at the link above has several samples of using different languages

Comment: @AlexK The language is actually an upcoming one.I am searching for smoething easy like setting the classpath and some other data to get a tag like <visagec> for compilation and <visage> for running the program ?

Comment: Did you find `visage` ant task? If you want to write your own task you can read this articles: http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html

Comment: @AlexK Nope visage ant task does not exist. It is an upcoming language still under development. I want to make a new ant task. I will go through the manual. Since the language is very new I am a bit confused whether I would be able to generate the task?? :-/

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh Alex gave you all the answers you will ever need from this forum. I suggest you answer yourself, after you figure out what to do and accept your answer.

Comment: @FailedDev definitely I would follow up and put the correct answer and tag it as a wiki. :) Thanks

Comment: @FailedDev Actually I got the answers from the links which Alex gave me. So i guess I would either prepare a small post so that things are aligned or I will try putting it in some better way.

Comment: @FailedDev please mark my answer as a WIKI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources mentioned by Alex were really useful and I was amazed to see how easy it was to make a little changes here and there and get through it.The links that helped me were:-

- [ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.htm](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.htm)
- [ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html)
- [ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can achieve what you need using an [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) - where you execute your compiler using a system command? The [apply task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/apply.html) might also be useful.

If you do implement your own compiler task, I would suggest looking at the source code of an existing Ant compilation task, e.g. [org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Javac.java?view=markup).

If you do implement your own task, then the references suggested in AlexK's comment are required reading. I'll copy them here:

- [Writing Your Own Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html)
- [Tutorial: Writing Tasks](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html)